# Why is the frequency function of a function of a random variable the sum of the variable's frequency function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $Y = g(X)$, where $X$ is a discrete random variable, and the fact that the frequency function of $X$ is $p(x)$, then the following is true:

$$p_Y(y_i) = \sum_{x \in A_{i}} p(x)$$

where $x \in A_i$ if $g(x)=y_i$.

The reasoning is along the lines:

\begin{align}
p_Y(Y=y_i) &= p_Y(g(X) = y_i)
\\&=p_X(x \in g^{-1}(y_i))
\end{align}

But I don't understand why 'we' sum over all the $x\in A_i$?

Comment: Maybe thinking about a simple example would help? Imagine $X$ is the outcome of a die throw and $Y=X $ mod $2$, i.e. is the outcome odd or even.

Comment: Your notation is misleading. Try to combine the following two facts:
1) Your definition of $A_i$ could be written as $A_i=g^{-1}(y_i)$.
2) $g^{-1}(y_i)$ is a set, so the term $X=g^{-1}(y_i)$ doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @AlecB-G thanks for the advice... Going through the example you mentioned led my reasoning to be something like: $g(X)$ is a surjective map ('for every $y$ there is an $x$') and thus the sum has the effect of 'rolling up' or 'grouping' outcomes.

Comment: @Benjamin I completely missed that! Thank you, I believe the correct statement would instead be $p_X(x \in g^{-1}(y_i))$ ?